# How do I run a SQL Server trace to start and end at specific times?

Tags: sql-server-2005, profiler, trace, sql-server-profiler

I found the recipe for creating a SQL Profiler trace.

How do I set up something to have this trace start and end at specific times, can I do this with a management task??

We are trying to find when and how locks or failed connections may be occurring but we don't know when they will occur -- a very intermittent problem.

Another solution would be to explain how I could run such a trace for a couple weeks without having logs get too big, can the trace files' save location be manually specified??

Thank you, Tom

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "failed connections"? Login Failures? If so these are already captured by the default trace.

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM sys.traces t
CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(t.path, default) f
WHERE f.EventClass=20
```

Also what do you mean by "locks"? It sounds like you might want to investigate setting up the [Blocked Process report](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191168.aspx). This should be relatively light weight and capable of running for weeks at a time as long as you configure the [blocked process threshold option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181150.aspx) sensibly.

You can use SQL Profiler to set up the trace initially and then script the trace definition from the export menu and put it in a [start up stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191129.aspx)

Comment: I've only been told 'locks,' I know a template exists for tsql_locks, I planned to start with that since that's all I've been told. Based on this I will start with your suggestion to use the default plus try one with the locks template. Thank you, Tom

Comment: @Tom That template seems pretty heavyweight as it records **all** the SQL Statements on the server I doubt it would be suitable for running for extended periods.

Comment: Thank you...I have not yet understood how to make it stop/start when I need it to do so...I turned it on/off a couple times. I must do more searching and reading. :) I'll try your suggestion too.